# Set up Docker for gulp

Tags: docker, gulp

I am currently learning Docker and already managed to set up my Django project. My Bootstrap template uses gulp watch (locally) & gulp build (production).

How can I set up my Dockerfile and docker-compose in order to run these gulp commands? From my current understanding, I need two different docker-compose files.

docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  web:
    build: .
    command: python3 manage.py migrate --noinput
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - SECRET_KEY=XYZ
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
```

Comment: Did you include the Dockerfile from the wrong project?  That looks like a plain-Python setup, not something JavaScript-based.

Comment: Currently, that's my Django project setup. I think that's exactly my question / problem right now that I don't know what to include in order to make `gulp watch` / `gulp build` work with my setup.